# Unable to Parse Multiple IN1 Segment in HL7 using HAPI TERSER

Tags: hl7, hapi, nhapi

I am receiving HL7 messages version 2.5.1.

```
MSH|..
PID|..
PV1|..
ORC|..
IN1|1|...
IN1|2|....
```

So in the above example **IN1** is repeating, however when i try to Parse the **second IN1 segment with TERSER** it throws an exception ***"Can't create repetition #1 of Structure IN1 - this Structure is non-repeating"***.

```
This is what i have tried so far

    string insurance = terser.Get("/.INSURANCE/.IN1(0)-1"); // Works fine
    string insurance = terser.Get("/.INSURANCE/.IN1(1)-1"); // Throws exception
string insurance = terser.Get("/.INSURANCE(0)/.IN1(0)-1"); // Works fine
    string insurance = terser.Get("/.INSURANCE(1)/.IN1(0)-1"); // Throws exception
```

Comment: How does the message header look like?

Comment: Message header: MSH|^~\&|Test|test|||20160309072750-0500||OML^O21^OML_O21|f9194efc-6ae2-42ea-ae28-40f8d7500a5a|T|2.5.1|||AL|NE|||||

Comment: Should there not the common order group (ORC .) follow the insurance group?

Comment: Do you have a sample of HL7?

Comment: @sqlab - As i have posted in my question  there is a ORC segement        -  MSH|..
PID|..
PV1|..
ORC|..
IN1|1|...
IN1|2|....

Comment: this is the sample  -    MSH|.....

PID|1|...

PV1|1|...

IN1|1|...

IN1|2|...

GT1|1|...

ORC|NW|...

OBR|1|...

DG1|1|...

DG1|2|...

ORC|NW|...

OBR|2|...

DG1|1|...

OBX|1|...

OBX|2|...

Answer (score 1):

I just started learning about HAPI as well. I notice that in your example you did not specify how you parse the message. Most than likey, it was parse into a generic message using the terser. If that is the case, I think it should look something like this

```
string insurance = terser.Get("/.INSURANCE/.IN12-1");
```

I believe Generic Message has no groups and to access this segment probably need to use IN12 instead of IN1(1)

Answer (score 1):

You are close but you are using a repeating group on IN1 which is not a repeating segment. Remember INSURANCE group is repeating the segments within are not:

```
Try:

/.INSURANCE(0)/.IN1-1"

/.INSURANCE(1)/.IN1-1"




"/.INSURANCE(1)/.IN1(0)-1" 

works because there's only one IN1 segment in the group (rep 0 defaults to the 1st segment in the group):
```

From the [Terser](https://hapifhir.github.io/hapi-hl7v2/base/apidocs/index.html) api read up on the section on groups:

> ...
>
> group_spec: ["."] group_name_pattern
>
> Here, a . indicates that the group should be searched for (using a
>   SegmentFinder) starting at the current location in the message. The
>   wildcards "*" and "?" represent any number of arbitrary characters,
>   and a single arbitrary character, respectively. For example, "M*" and
>   "?S?" match MSH. The first group with a name that matches the given
>   group_name_pattern will be matched.
>
> The segment_spec is analogous to the group_spec.
>
> As another example, the following subcomponent in an SIU_S12 message:
>
> msg.getSIU_S12_RGSAISNTEAIGNTEAILNTEAIPNTE(1).getSIU_S12_AIGNTE().getAIG().getResourceGroup(1).getIdentifier();
>
> ...
>
> is referenced by all of the following location_spec:
>   /SIU_S12_RGSAISNTEAIGNTEAILNTEAIPNTE(1)/SIU_S12_AIGNTE/AIG-5(1)-1 
>   /*AIG*(1)/SIU_S12_AIGNTE/AIG-5(1)-1  /*AIG*(1)/.AIG-5(1)
>
> The search function only iterates through rep 0 of each group. Thus if
>   rep 0 of the first group in this example was desired instead of rep 1,
>   the following syntax would also work (since there is only one AIG
>   segment position in SUI_S12):
>
> /.AIG-5(1)